# Close all bootstrap accordions

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to save my accordions as an image with HTML2CANVAS. For this i open up all accordions and everything's nice, but then they won't close later on. I digged around and found this great code:

```
function openAccordions(){
    $('.panel-collapse:not(".in")')
    .collapse('show'); 
}

function closeAccordions(){
    $('.panel-collapse.in')
    .collapse('hide'); 
}
```

By the looks of it and googling around this should work, although the function openAccordions() work but closeAccordions() does not (elements stay collapsed).

Any ideas how to work around or why this particular code might not work?

Comment: This would be easier to debug with the HTML and a Bootply or JSFiddle example, but for starters, are there any errors in your console? (F12 Console tab)

Comment: Nope, no errors in console..

Comment: Can you provide the HTML or a Bootply/JSFiddle? Honestly, it's hard to test otherwise...

Comment: Apparently it works in jsfiddle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try check for visibility. Like so:

```
function openAccordions(){
    $('.panel-collapse').not(':visible')
    .collapse('show'); 
}

function closeAccordions(){
    $('.panel-collapse').is(':visible')
    .collapse('hide'); 
}
```